# VBA - Define range variables through looping

Tags: excel, vba

I'm wondering if it's possible to define range variables through a for..next loop?

Something like that

```
Public Sub DefineRanges()
 Dim i As Long
 Dim rngLine1, rngLine2 As Range

 For i = 1 To 2
    Set Replace("rngLinex", "x", i) = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & i)
 Next i
End Sub
```

or like that

```
Public Sub DefineRanges()
 Dim i As Long
 Dim rngLine1, rngLine2 As Range

 For i = 1 To 2
    Set rngLine & i = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & i)
 Next i
End Sub
```

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 4):

As @JohnColeman stated use an array of ranges:

```
Sub defineranges()
Dim i As Long
Dim RngArr(1 To 2) As Range

For i = 1 To 2
    Set RngArr(i) = ThisWorkbook.Worksheets("Sheet1").Range("A" & i)
Next i

For i = 1 To 2
    Debug.Print RngArr(i).Value
Next i
End Sub
```

Comment: This is the way to go. My second suggestion doesn't actually work (at least not obviously so) so I deleted that comment.

Comment: when I try to apply the same thig to string it doesn't really work.. any suggestions please? Does Dim strArr(1 To 2) As String seem to be applicable?